# Why is Passing a Javascript Callback to Callback did not work on android phone and works on simulator in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I don't know why the code below works fine in simulator and failed in Android phone.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.codename1.components.WebBrowser;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.javascript.JSFunction;
import com.codename1.javascript.JSObject;
import com.codename1.javascript.JavascriptContext;
import com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
      Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
final WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser(){
    @Override
    public void onLoad(String url) {
        // Placed on onLoad because we need to wait for page 
        // to load to interact with it.

        BrowserComponent c = (BrowserComponent)this.getInternal();

        // Create a Javascript context for this BrowserComponent
        JavascriptContext ctx = new JavascriptContext(c);

        // Now use the context to interact with Javascript environment....



          JSObject window = (JSObject)ctx.get("window");
     window.set("addAsync", new JSFunction(){

            public void apply(JSObject self, final Object[] args) {
                Double a = (Double)args[0];
                Double b = (Double)args[1];
                JSObject callback = (JSObject)args[2];

                double result = a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
                Dialog.show("testing",result +"", "ok","");
                callback.call(new Object[]{new Double(result)});

            }

        });




    //    Dialog.show("Content", pageContent, "OK", "Cancel");
    } 
};
// b.setURL("jar:///mydata.html");



b.setPage("<html><body>"
        + ""+

"    <head>\n" +
"        <title>Addition Example</title>\n" +
"    </head>\n" +
"    <body>\n" +
"        <div>Addition Example</div>\n" +
"        <p><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"input1\"/> +\n" +
"            <input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"input2\"/> =\n" +
"            <span id=\"result\"></span>\n" +
"        </p>\n" +
"        <p><button id=\"calculate\">Calculate</button></p>\n" +
"        <script>\n" +
"            \n" +
"       document\n" +
"    .getElementById('calculate')\n" +
"    .addEventListener('click', function(){\n" +
"        var aField = document.getElementById('input1');\n" +
"        var bField = document.getElementById('input2');\n" +
"        var a = parseFloat(aField.value);\n" +
"        var b = parseFloat(bField.value);\n" +
"        window.addAsync(a, b, function(result){\n" +
"           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;\n" +
"        });\n" +
"    }, true);\n" +
"     \n" +
  "            \n" +
"        </script>\n" 


        + ""
        + " </body></html>", null);



hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, b);
hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

I used the code on my simulator to test its capability and it was working fine. When I built and installed it on my Android phone, to my surprise, it did not work as expected. I dont know what I need to add to make this work for me on phone. Pls I need your help. Thanks

Screen short on the simulator

[image]

[image]

When I click on calculate button on my phone it does not bring any message and no calculation was done. Pls I am just using this to test run. I have gone far about the project. Thanks for your help

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get any error(s)?

Comment: I did not get any error. I was expecting it to give the same result as the one of the simulator. it just kept silent when I click on the button. thanks for your concern Lajos Arpad

Comment: Could you modify it to write some helpful messages to the log file so you can determine the program state later from there which could lead you to the solution?

Comment: Debugging the bridge stuff is hell on wheels. Try to narrow this down on whether this is an issue in the callback code or the first call to async. Try to print some logs and see if it works and onLoad is invoked properly. Look in DDMS/logcat to see the output and whether anything else is logged

Comment: Pls sir, help me to review the code above. I copied the completed code and paste for debugging. I did not receive any error in the logs. The code  is working on the simulator but failed on phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the Javascript bridge that affected some versions of Android (not all).  I have fixed it [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/ce5bbd28e5e1bc297f292ccf30e550de08810250), so that your code will work after the next server update on Friday.

If you change the 2nd parameter of "setPage()" to some dummy URL (e.g. http://www.codenameone.com), it should also workaround this issue in the mean time.